# É possível fazer um UPDATE com dados de outra tabela?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

Sei que é possível executar um `INSERT` com dados de outra tabela:

```
INSERT INTO Tabela (Col01, Col02, Col03)
    SELECT Col01, Col02, Col03
    FROM Outra_tabela
    WHERE Condicao = 'qualquer coisa'
```

Mas gostaria de fazer o mesmo com um `UPDATE`. Algo equivalente à isso:

```
UPDATE Tabela SET Col01, Col02, Col03
    SELECT Col01, Col02, Col03
    FROM Outra_tabela
    WHERE Condicao = 'qualquer coisa'
WHERE Tabela.id = Outra_tabela.id
```

É possível? Como?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

É possível fazendo um **`Inner Join`**

```
UPDATE Tabela
SET
  Tabela.Col01 = Outra_tabela.Col01,
  Tabela.Col02 = Outra_tabela.Col02
FROM
  Tabela
INNER JOIN Outra_tabela
  ON Tabela.id = Outra_tabela.id
WHERE
  Condicao = 'Qualquer coisa'
```

[Coloquei o código no GitHub para referência futura.](https://github.com/jfbueno/Stack-Overflow-Portugues/blob/master/SQL/SQL%20Server/170542/inner-join-update.sql)