# Update com dados de outra tabela

Tags: sql, sql-server

Preciso inserir os dados de uma coluna da tabela B dentro da tabela A, segui o que foi descrito nesta pergunta: [É possível fazer um UPDATE com dados de outra tabela?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/170542/%c3%89-poss%c3%advel-fazer-um-update-com-dados-de-outra-tabela)

Porém, está me retornando o seguinte erro: *The multi-part identifier "tc.parcelas" could not be bound.*

A query que estou executando é a seguinte:

```
UPDATE banco.SCHEMA.tb_contrato
SET    tc.parcelas = tp.ultimaparcela
FROM   banco.SCHEMA.tb_contrato tc
       INNER JOIN (SELECT idcontrato,
                          Substring(Max(parcela), 5, 3) AS UltimaParcela,
                          datacessao
                   FROM   banco.SCHEMA.tb_parcela
                   GROUP  BY idcontrato,
                             datacessao) tp
               ON tc.idcontrato = tp.idcontrato
 WHERE tp.datacessao > '2019-09-01'
   AND tc.parcelas IS NULL;
```

Comment: Só para confirmar, o nome da coluna está correto, a tabela tb_contrato possui uma coluna chamada parcelas? Me parece que não tem relação mas para desencargo experimente deixar somente o alias _tc_ após o _Update_ em vez do nome da tabela.

Comment: @imex O nome da coluna está correto sim, e quando fiz a alteração que você sugeriu, deu erro de syntax

Comment: Qual versão do SQL Server você está utilizando? Qual mensagem de erro foi exibida após a alteração? Não comentei antes porque não tem relação com os erros de sintaxe mas pelo menos na teoria a tabela derivada utilizada no Join pode retornar mais de uma linha para um mesmo id_contrato e nesse caso o resultado talvez não seja o esperado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só troca o inicio da query

```
UPDATE tc
SET    tc.parcelas = tp.ultimaparcela
FROM   banco.SCHEMA.tb_contrato tc
       INNER JOIN (SELECT idcontrato,
                          Substring(Max(parcela), 5, 3) AS UltimaParcela,
                          datacessao
                   FROM   banco.SCHEMA.tb_parcela
                   GROUP  BY idcontrato,
                             datacessao) tp
               ON tc.idcontrato = tp.idcontrato
 WHERE tp.datacessao > '2019-09-01'
   AND tc.parcelas IS NULL;
```